# every keypress for prompt-sync in javascript repeats the prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, prompt

Code:

```js
var prompt = require("prompt-sync")()

function start() {
  var whatbox = prompt('What box would you like to open?(ALL LOWER CASE)') 
  if (whatbox == "School") {
    box("School")
  } else if (whatbox == "Park") {
    box("Park")
  } else if (whatbox == "Tech"
  } {
    box("Tech")
  } else {
    console.log("That is NOT a box! Try again and check your spelling!")
  }
}
start()
```

Error:
The prompt keeps on repeating every time I press a key.

Comment: You're missing a `)` on the line `else if (whatbox == "Tech"`. How is this running at all?

Comment: all the boxes and "Tech" and "School" and "Park" are in another part of the code which works fine.

Comment: @Barmar i think that was just when I put it into stack overflow
v

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual code, with proper indentation.

Comment: var prompt = require("prompt-sync")()

function start() {


  var whatbox = prompt('What box would you like to open? (ALL LOWER CASE)')
      if (whatbox == "School")
      {box("School")}

      else if (whatbox == "Park")
      {box("Park")}

      else if (whatbox == "Tech")
      {box("Tech")}

   else {console.log("That is NOT a box! Try again and check your spelling!")}
     
}
start()

Comment: Put it in the question, with proper formatting.

Comment: do you need everything because it is very long and not really important to the error?

Comment: We just need a [mre]

Comment: i dont know what that means i am really new to this

Comment: DId you try clicking on it?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var prompt = require("prompt-sync")()

function start() {
  console.log("What box would you like to open?(ALL LOWER CASE)")
  var whatbox = prompt("Your input >> ")
  if (whatbox == "School") {
    box("School")
  } else if (whatbox == "Park") {
    box("Park")
  } else if (whatbox == "Tech"
  } {
    box("Tech")
  } else {
    console.log("That is NOT a box! Try again and check your spelling!")
  }
}
start()
```

The prompt-sync has this problem where if your prompt text/qustion is too long it fails when refreshing it. To solve this problem, you can simply console.log question and then ask for input.